# Como organizar um projeto em node

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, node.js, organização-de-projeto

Gostaria de alguma ideia de como eu poderia organizar um projeto em node.js, atualmente os arquivos estão dessa forma:

```
- router.js
- controller
    L controllerUser.js
    L controllerAuth.js
    L ...
- service
    L mongodbConnection.js
    L serviceUser.js
    L ...
```

No serviço basicamente é um CRUD (por enquanto):

```
const mongodbConnection = require('./mongodbConnection.js');

//Find document of collection user by propriety name
module.exports.findByName = async function(object) {
    let connection = await mongodbConnection.connection(collection);

    let select = await connection.find(object);

    return select.toArray();
}
```

No serviço a conexão com o banco de dados, no caso, mongodb, é através de um módulo:

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

module.exports.connection = async function(collection) {
    try {
        //Connect MongoDB
        let database = await mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017');
        console.log('Connected successfully');

        //Select and return database connection
        return database.db('dataPOA').collection(collection);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }
}
```

- Iniciar uma nova conexão no início de cada função é correto? Parece muita repetição de código, tem como melhorar?
- Como fechar essa conexão? Ou devo deixar aberta mesmo?
- Não seria prudente colocar esse código que executa funções no banco dentro de um `try catch`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O que costumo usar é mais ou menos isso aqui:

```
- src/
    - main.js
    - modules/
        - [controllers]
        - [models]
        - database.js
        - [script variados: util.js, http-server.js, socket-server.js, etc]
    - views/
        - [templates: mustache|handlebars|whatever]
    - routes/
        - user.js (/user routes)
        - admin.js (/admin routes)
        - etc
- test/
    - [units]
    - [acceptances]
    - etc
- util/
    - [script empacotador do app]
    - [scripts variados]
- package.json
- [yarn.lock|package-lock.json]
```

Em database.js vamos ter o seguinte:

```
'use strict';

const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

module.exports.isReady = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        //Connect MongoDB
        let database = await mongoClient.connect(
            'mongodb://localhost:27017', {useNewUrlParser: true}
        );
        console.log('Connected successfully');

        //Select and return database connection
        let db = database.db('dataPOA');

        module.exports.conn = db;
        resolve();
    }
    catch (err) {
        reject(err);
    }
});
```

A idéia é você abrir uma conexão permanente no início da aplicação. Essa conexão nunca será fechada, você vai reusar ela por todo seu app.

Como o estabelescimneto da conexão é asíncrono nós precisamos de uma maneira de indentificar que a conexão está pronta para uso e que podemos startar nosso aplicativo, daí o uso da `Promise` `isReady` (em `module.exports.isReady`). A promise só vai ser resolvida quando a conexão tiver sido estabelescida.

Tendo em mente que o ponto de start da aplicação é o arquivo `main.js`, nele vamos ter algo parecido com isto:

```
'use strict';
const DB = require('./modules/database');

DB.isReady.then(async () => {
    console.info('Datbase is ready');

    // let server = HttpServer();
    // socket server

    // um arquivo qualquer que faz algo com a db
    require('./modules/dosomething');

    // mais requires
    // etc
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('damn', err);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

`modules/dosomething` é um arquivo qualquer, nele temos um exemplo de como você vai usar a conexão pré-estabelescida:

```
'use strict';
// dosomething.js
const DB = require('./database');

const collection = DB.conn.collection('maybeMongodbIsNotTheBestChoice');

// obs poderíamos usar async/await aqui sem problemas 
// caso isso estivesse encapsulado em uma funćão async
collection.insertMany([
    {name: 'afasdfasdfa'},
    {name: 'erqwqwerwqerwqer'}
]).then(() => {
    return collection.find({}, {limit: 5}).toArray();
}).then((res) => {
    console.info(res);
});
```

E é basicamente isso, sempre que quiser usar a database você vai fazer require de modules/database.js e utilizar `[DB].conn`. A diferenća crucial desse modelo para o seu é que aqui `DB.conn.[algum método]` (`DB.conn.collection('minhacollection')`) **não** estabelesce uma nova conexão com o banco, apenas reusa a que foi feita em `main.js` no primeiro require de `modules/database.js`. No seu exemplo **toda** vez que chamamos `mongodbConnection.collection('minhacollection')` estamos estabelescendo uma nova conexão com o banco e a própria documentaćão do mongodb já [recomenda evitar](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connection-pooling) esse pattern.

Também disponibilizei um exemplo em https://github.com/BrunoRB/so-pt-304009-como-organizar-um-projeto-em-node, basta clonar o projeto, rodar npm|yarn install dentro da pasta principal e executar `node src/main.js`.

Por fim espero que fique claro que embora o exemplo use `mongodb` esse modelo não é restrito a ela. Em dbs como mysql ou sqlite você pode (e eu recomendo) usar uma padrão similar, com as alterações adequadas é claro. Por exemplo: usando `mysql` você não só quer esperar que a conexão tenha sido estabelescida, mas também que todas as suas tabelas, views, triggers, etc, tenham sido criadas antes de comećar a utlizar a conexão. Para isso precisariamos adaptar o `isReady` de forma que ele só chame o `resolve` após todos os seus `CREATE TABLE` (e similares) terem completado.

Comment: Eu venho do PHP e é meio estranho pensar em criar uma conexão e manter ela sempre aberta. E o uso do `try catch`, recomenda ou tanto faz?

Comment: Como você usa essa conexão nos seus controladores ou roteadores? Importa o módulo do banco novamente?

Comment: Entendo seu ponto, é realmente exótico vir de uma linguagem onde você instancia uma conexão a cada nova requisićão e se deparar com node e ter a conexão sempre aberta, mas isso é normal.

Sobre `try...catch`, o app não tem uso sem a DB, então você pode colocar o try...catch, logar o erro e dar um `process.exit(1)` no catch, ou simplesmente deixar explodir e falhar.

Para usar a conexão eu _sempre_ importo o arquivo `database.js`, onde estabelesci ela, no caso o: `const connection = require('./modules/database.js');`

Comment: Ok. Ainda não entendi muito bem, no caso em tenho os arquivos dentro da pasta `service`, onde tenho as funções que acessam o banco, eu preciso dessa variável lá, como ela chega até lá? poderia dar um exemplo de uma função de acesso ao banco?

Comment: Os arquivos de `service/` fariam `const connection = require('./../modules/database.js');`, tendo acesso ao objeto de conexão que já foi criado quando você startou o app rodando algo como `node main.js`. Estou meio sem tempo agora, mas se ainda precisar amanhã a noite crio um exemplo completo para você ver a ideia em funcionamento.

Comment: Isso já é mais ou menos o que eu faço, mas parece que dessa forma ele está buscando uma nova conexão em cada `require`

Comment: No que você faz é exportada uma funćão, essa funćão instancia uma nova connection toda vez que é invocada. Então se você tem `const c = require('mongodbConnection.js').connection(collection)`, isso faz gerar uma nova conexão porque roda todo aquele bloco de funćão que vc exportou. No que eu sugeri não, a conexão seria criada no database.js já quando ele é required pela primeira vez, requires subsquentes não criam uma nova conexão por em node require() é cacheado. Toda a diferenća está em você exportar uma funćão que gera uma connection, onde eu sugiro exportar a _connection_ diretamente.

Comment: Se tiver tiver por favor adiciona aquele exemplo por favor

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam veja se está mais claro agora, adicionei um exemplo (quase) completo usando mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Há pouco tempo conheci um *framework* com padrão MVC para NodeJS. Chama-se [Adonis](https://adonisjs.com/).
É extremamente organizado e herda um pouco do estilo do Laravel.

O único mal é que não tem suporte a MongoDB, visto que trabalha com SQL em um padrão conhecido como *active record*. No entanto, não vejo isso como um problema.

- https://adonisjs.com/

Comment: Nesse caso, sim, é um problema, mas não invalida a resposta. Se puder acrescente o por quê de ser organizado e o funcionamento do framework

Answer (score 1):

Guilherme, lê esse material. Eu me basei nele pra estruturar meu projeto, e ele explica muito bem os diversos casos que podem ser adotados e o melhor deles:

http://www.matera.com/blog/post/estrutura-de-diretorios-em-projetos-angularjs
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure