# Node.js: Como extrair informações do banco de dados e mostrar em páginas HTML

Tags: mysql, node.js

eu aprendi como faz para buscar informações do banco de dados MySQL, mas eu não consigo manipular esses dados para expor em páginas HTML. O código que vou expor embaixo eu peguei do w3school:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Prestem atenção na parte que eu pego os dados, ele fica armazenado na variável result, só que não dá pra manipular essa informação fora do escopo da função. Como eu pego esses dados e coloco o resultado em uma página HTML? É possível fazer isso sem framework? Se não for, que framework usar?

Comment: Você pode fazer na mão com os módulos http ou usar o express (que é o que a maioria faz)

Comment: Quando eu extraio as informações, ele fica preso no contexto da função. Como eu faço pra exportar esses dados pra outros módulos?

Comment: Você precisa criar e exportar uma função que execute a query e retorne o resultado. Da uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304009/) acho que irá te ajudar

Answer (score 1):

#### Callbacks:

Os dados não podem sair de dentro do escopo dessa função já que ela representa um *callback*, isto é, não é executada na ordem do código, sendo chamada somente quando os dados são carregados da base de dados.

> Para saber mais sobre *callbacks*, sugiro ler [essa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback).

#### Opte por usar um framework já existente:

Para facilitar esse processo, muitos desenvolvedores optam por usar  *frameworks*. Abaixo vou citá-los na minha ordem de preferência:

1. [AdonisJs](http://adonisjs.com), um framework MVC, similar ao Laravel e Ruby on Rails;
2. [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/), um framework minimalista para Node.JS;
3. [hapi.js](https://hapijs.com/), ainda minimalista, mas com alguns recursos a mais que o Express.